# Powershell - Manager Direct Reports and Group Membership

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that automates the process of notifying managers of their direct reports and what security groups they belong.  We use the direct report attribute to identify managers and those they manage.  Ultimately I'd like the script to query AD and automatically email the manager with a list of their direct reports and what security groups they are a member.  Below is how far I've gotten with my script.  When I run the script, an email is generated but the content only includes numbers for the security groups.  Any suggestions on how I can fix this, or if another script exists people know of would be great.  I tried to remove any internal information so hopefully I didn't break what I already had.

Thank You!

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$today = (Get-Date).ToString()

# Html
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:Lavender ;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


# Email Variables
$smtp = "internal.mailrelay.com"
$from = "operations@company.com>"
$subject = "Managers - Direct Report's Group Membership"

$managers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties name, directreports, EmailAddress | where {$_.directreports -ne $Null}

foreach ($i in $managers) 
{
    $mgrname = $i.Name
    $mgremail = $i.EmailAddress
    $dreports = $i.directreports
    foreach ($d in $dreports)
    {
        $user = get-aduser $d -properties *
        write-host "*** " $user.name " is a member of the following groups: " #$user.memberof
        $mems = $user.memberof -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1' | convertTo-html -Head $a -Body "<H2>Group Membership.</H2>"
        $dreport = $d -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1'

        $body = "Report Date $today ."
        $body += "`n"
        $body += "<H3>The direct reports for $mgrname<H3>"
        $body += "`n"
        $body += "<H3>Direct Report: $dreport</H3>"
        $body += "`n"
        $body += $mems
        $body += "`n"

        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $mgremail -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ConvertTo-HTML doesn't play nice with most things. It really, really wants to take an Object, vs a String, so one solution to your issue would be to convert each group name to an object like this:

```
        $mems = $user.memberof -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1' | %{New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Group Membership'=$_}} | convertTo-html -Head $a -Body "<H2>Group Membership.</H2>"
```

That will stop outputting numbers and will actually give you the names of your groups in a table, but I don't think it's what you really want since you're embedding it into the middle of an email. What you probably want is to lose most of the switches you have at the end and just use -Fragment. That's up to you though. This at least will stop you from getting the table full of numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at that tomorrow morning.  I've searched for similar scripts but haven't found anything yet, so I'll continue banging away at what I have so far.

Comment: That looks to have fixed this, but I have another problem so I'll ask another question.  Thank you!